# OneOf Arrays in FireCMS - Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have started using fireCMS. I'm trying to set up an array of images and strings. The doc's tell me that.

> oneOf# Use this field if you would like to have an array of
> properties. It is useful if you need to have values of different types
> in the same array. Each entry of the array is an object with the
> shape:

```
{ type: "YOUR_TYPE", value: "YOUR_VALUE"}
```

https://firecms.co/docs/properties/array

here is the code I have written

```
content: {
        title: "Content",
        description: "This is your page content",
        dataType: "array",
        oneOf: {
                    type:'string',
                    value: "Copy",
                    config:{
                        markdown:true
                    }
        }
```

then I want to add an image, but after I get this working...

I'm getting the following error.

> TypeScript error in /Users/.../App.tsx(145,25):
> Type '{ type: string; title: string; config: { markdown: true; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ properties: Record<string, StringProperty | BooleanProperty | NumberProperty | TimestampProperty | GeopointProperty | ReferenceProperty<...> | MapProperty<...> | ArrayProperty<...>>; typeField?: string | undefined; valueField?: string | undefined; }'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'type' does not exist in type '{ properties: Record<string, StringProperty | BooleanProperty | NumberProperty | TimestampProperty | GeopointProperty | ReferenceProperty<...> | MapProperty<...> | ArrayProperty<...>>; typeField?: string | undefined; valueField?: string | undefined; }'

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have added *type:'string'* but it's throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out, I was missing "properties", hope this helps someone in the future.

```
       content: {
        title: "Content",
        description: "This is your page content",
        dataType: "array",
        


        oneOf:{properties: {
            copy: {
                title: "Copy",
                dataType: "string",
                config:{
                    markdown:true
                }
            },
            image: {
                title: "Main Image",
                dataType: "string",
                config: {
                    storageMeta: {
                        mediaType: "image",
                        storagePath: "images",
                        acceptedFiles: ["image/*"]
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! I will add some better examples in the docs :)